# Eye in password field does not appear using bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, font-awesome-5

When using Bootstrap v5 and FontAwesome v5, I cannot get get the eyeball to appear to the right side of the form. Instead, it pulls the password field further to the right than the username field and the eye does not show.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
   <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
   <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
   <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
   <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="">
   <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i></span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const togglePassword = document.querySelector("#togglePassword");
const password = document.querySelector("#password");

togglePassword.addEventListener("click", function () {
   
// toggle the type attribute
const type = password.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
password.setAttribute("type", type);

// toggle the eye icon
this.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
});
```

Comment: do you have the font-awesome font / css loaded? do other icons work in your site (eg is this the only one that's not showing)?

Comment: Yes, my icons work. When I remove the margin-left, it appears, but outside of the input field.

Comment: For Bootstrap icons. Replace "far fa-eye-slash" with "bi bi-eye".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the icon overlaps the input, it goes beneath the input tag. To fix this you need to set the `<i>` tag with a higher [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) value. Try with `z-index: 100` to make it appear on top even when the input is clicked.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="input-group mb-3">
   <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
   <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="">
   <i class="far fa-eye" id="togglePassword" 
   style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: -30px; z-index: 100;"></i>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: If you want the password field and the username field to be in the same width, you can try wrapping the icon inside the `input-group-text` and remove the styling `margin-left: -30px; z-index: 100;` since `input-group-text` overlaps over the input field.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="">
  <span class="input-group-text">
    <i class="far fa-eye" id="togglePassword" 
   style="cursor: pointer"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

**Edit 2:** In your JavaScript code, you are hiding the eye icon with `this.classList.toggle('fa-eye')`. This function removes the class `fa-eye` when it is available in the `classList` of the `togglePassword` element and adds the above class when it is not available.

I assume that you want to show hide password icons which might be the  [`eye-slash` icon](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/eye-slash?style=regular) when the user is currently in the text format. So you can add

```
this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
```

as below

```
const togglePassword = document.querySelector("#togglePassword");
const password = document.querySelector("#password");

togglePassword.addEventListener("click", function () {
   
  // toggle the type attribute
  const type = password.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
  password.setAttribute("type", type);
  // toggle the eye icon
  this.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
  this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="">
  <span class="input-group-text">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword" 
   style="cursor: pointer"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This partially worked - I now see the eye, however, the password field still stretches to the right past the username field above it.

Comment: @germanshedder I have modified the solution

Comment: I did that, the fields do match the width now. However, when I click the eye, it disappears. I added my javascript code to the original post.

Comment: added more explanation and a kind reminder is that in your future posts make your question be focused to a paticular problem at the beginning and remember Stack Overflow is not a site only for debugging advices

Comment: It works in Chrome, however, in Edge, I see the eye appear in the input field as well.

Comment: Is there another site better suited for debugging code?

Comment: You mean after implementing the JS solution?

Answer (score 3):

Example using feather icons with Jquery 3.3 with Bootstrap 5

```js
  feather.replace({ 'aria-hidden': 'true' });

$(".togglePassword").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var type = $(this).parent().parent().find(".password").attr("type");
      console.log(type);
      if(type == "password"){
          $("svg.feather.feather-eye").replaceWith(feather.icons["eye-off"].toSvg());
          $(this).parent().parent().find(".password").attr("type","text");
      }else if(type == "text"){
          $("svg.feather.feather-eye-off").replaceWith(feather.icons["eye"].toSvg());
          $(this).parent().parent().find(".password").attr("type","password");
      }
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js" integrity="sha384-uO3SXW5IuS1ZpFPKugNNWqTZRRglnUJK6UAZ/gxOX80nxEkN9NcGZTftn6RzhGWE" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="p-3 mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input class="form-control password" id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" value="secret!" required />
          <span class="input-group-text togglePassword" id="">
              <i data-feather="eye" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
          </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `z-index:2;` to your icon.
To prevent your eye icon being hidden when the input field is focused, you would need to add the following css code:-

```css
<style>
#password:focus ~ .far-fa-eye{
margin-left: -30px !important; 
cursor: pointer !important;
z-index: 5 !important;
}
</style>
```

Also, please share us a visual or code for your username field so that we can get a better view of what you mean.

PS: I would prefer to avoid inline css as much as possible. Inline css might be troublesome when it comes to debugging large css codes.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation Jquery 3.6.0 with Bootstrap 5

HTML

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input class="form-control password" id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required />
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="far fa-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"
            style="cursor: pointer"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".togglePassword").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var type = $(this).parent().parent().find(".password").attr("type");
console.log(type);
if(type == "password"){
    $(this).removeClass("fa-eye-slash");
    $(this).addClass("fa-eye");
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".password").attr("type","text");
}else if(type == "text"){
    $(this).removeClass("fa-eye");
    $(this).addClass("fa-eye-slash");
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".password").attr("type","password");
}});
```